# Android connectivity with Google cloud SQL

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to save the value of text box from Android activity to Google cloud SQL. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Start reading docs:

1. Communication from Android to GAE - see [Cloud Endpoins](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/)
2. Saving/retrieving data on GAE: see [using Cloud SQL service on GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide).